# Windows 8 desktop constant reloading, "thumbnail handler extraction host"

Tags: windows-8.1, system-restore, safe-mode

I have recently install the Nikon NEF codec and the Nikon nx d viewer on a Windows 8 laptop, after I restart Windows this happens: after i get into the desktop, it shows a full screen theme colour(green I my case) and then reload all the thumbnails in the desktop. It goes into a loop of this.

I am unable to do anything like uninstalling the softwares because it cuts all the actions once it reloads. I have try safe mode but it does exactly the same thing!! The problems is a process called "thumbnail handler extraction host", which there is 80 of them in the task manager dialogue.

Please help! I am running Windows 8.1, i7 4510u CPU, 8gb ram and a gt750m gpu.

Note, I have tried using the system restore point, It said it cannot delete any file because it can't access the files.
Second, I don't want to do a full system restore or refresh because I got lots of programs and files in it.

Comment: Do you have Norton, AVG or any other antivirus/internet security package installed? I have seen this a number of times and uninstalling whichever of the AVs fixed it - especially Norton and AVG... you can uninstall and then re-install and the problem should be gone. If you keep getting the Metro interface popping up then you need to click the desktop icon the moment your computer starts - otherwise this will happen.

Comment: Yes I do have avast av installed, but I have already disabled it from start up. And also it is not the metro screen since I use classic shell which skip the metro screen.

Comment: The "thumbnail handler extraction host" opening multiple times is related to an an AV issue, I'm sure of it. It's a pain to pinpoint the culprit. Try uninstalling Avast completely.... also go though your "Programs and Features" to make sure there isn't any other AVs installed... You might also want to try uninstalling classic shell at the same time and see if this helps in your quest to fix this issue... just one more thing to try :)

Comment: Thanks, however I can't even uninstall avast since it reload the desktop every 0.5 second :(

Comment: I know it's a pain but if you can kill all the thumbnail extraction host instances via the Task manager then you will, at some point, be able to control your machine properly for a few minutes. It's a paint, I know, I've been there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I simply boot up Windows with "safe mode with command prompt". I open notepad with cmd then click open file, I navigate to the Nikon installation folder(programs files) and then delete it!
Windows is now working, I run ccleaner to ensure all remaining file is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same problem on a Win 8.1 PC my wife uses. It appeared all at a sudden, while in the process of trivially opening an e-mail without any attachments.

After the fix - see below - the same mail could be opened and processed without any issues, so it certaily was not the culprit. I have no idea what caused the issue, but the described misbehavior is gone now.

**Warning:** After the fix, you might need to re-install newly installed apps.

```
[Alt]+[Ctrl]+[Del]
[Shift]+[RightClick on PowerIcon]
[Shift]+[Restart]
[Troubleshooting]
[Extended Options]
[Restore the system]
Select user
Enter password
[Continue]
Select most recent system restore point
[Continue]
[Finish]
[OK]
Wait some
[Restart]
[Close]
```